# Восстановление покупок Google Play

Tags: android, in-app-purchases, android-billing

При тестовой покупке всё происходит хорошо, но при возврате средств через панель разработчика, покупка все равно считается активной.

**Код восстановления покупок:**

```
@Override
public void onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {
    //Вызывается, когда история покупки была восстановлена,
    // и список всех принадлежащих идентификаторы продуктов был загружен из Google Play

    // так Вы сможете НУЖНУЮ покупку проверить
    for (String sku : bp.listOwnedProducts()) {
        boolean wasBouhtg = sku.equals(InAppBillingResources.getSKU_Disable_Ads());
        if (wasBouhtg) {
            // true - куплено
            // пишем в `SharedPreferences`, что отключили рекламу
            prefManager.setAdsStatus(false);
        } else {
            // false - не куплено

            prefManager.setAdsStatus(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Каким образом можно получить действительно актуальный список покупок?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел решение.
Библиотека использует кеширование купленных товаров, и метод listOwnedProducts() обращается
**именно к кэшу** , чтобы обновить кэш, необходимо вызывать метод **loadOwnedPurchasesFromGoogle()**. После этого список становится актуальным.